# Regex: How to return only one occurrence of a match even if there are multiple same occurrences?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the links from a web page, but there could be multiple occurrences of the same link.
Because I'm interested in getting all the links, I'm using the `match()` function which returns the same link twice(or multiple times, depending on how many identical links are on the page).

Example:

```
const results = [
    'http://example1.com','http://example1.com', 'http://example2.com','http://example2.com',
];
```

**One solution** would be to pass the array of matches to `Set()`.

```
const expected = [... new Set(results)];
expected // ["http://example1.com", "http://example2.com"]
```

Is there another way to get the expected result without making use of `Set()`, preferably still using regex ?

So the main problem is not removing duplicates from the array, but getting distinct values from regex.

[Here is some context](https://regex101.com/r/5tz37k/2)

Following the example, the result consists of an array of 4 items, namely 2 duplicates.

The expected result would be an array of **distinct** links. In this case, an array of 2 items.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate values from JS array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array)

Comment: I edited my post so people can focus attention on the actual problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to get only the last match by the lookahead assertion:

```js
/(https:\/\/\S+\/[a-z-0-9\?=]+-+\d+-+)(?!.*\1)/gs
```

Comment: Works, but extremely inefficient - see the 442379 steps? (best for OP to use his `Set`, IMO, and ideally an HTML parser instead of regex)

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt thank you! this is exactly what I've been looking for.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thank you for pointing out the efficiency problem. Could you elaborate on what you mean with those steps?

Comment: @AndreiGătej Just plug in his pattern into your regex101 and you'll see 442379 steps up at the top. It's too much.

Comment: Now I see. It's indeed too much.